# Views page menu shows up on all languages

Tags: views, 6, navigation

I am working on a old website built on Drupal 6 which has two languages. There is a views on which I created a page for each language, but their menus shows up on both languages. I tried different combinations of relationships, arguments and filters, which works on the content but not on the menus. How can I force a views page menu to display only on the correct language?

Comment: Are you talking about Menus from structure in Drupal? They have their own multilingual settings, it's not controled in Views. Check your menu multilingual settings, set it to translatable, or create two different menus each with its own language.

Comment: @prkos : I'm talking about menus created within "page settings" in the views page display.

Comment: When you add a menu entry through Views you still have to choose which Menu from Structure it belongs to. I'm guessing it still has to do with the multilingual settings for that Menu. Did you filter to Views to show specific language? Sorry I forgot where that option is in D6, or which modules you need to have enabled for View multilingual, check in that direction.

Comment: @prkos : I did filter the views for the language and I also added arguments and relationships related to the languages. The contend does not show up in the "wrong" language, but the menu still does. Both menus shows up in the primary menu (along with other menus added from contents), but there is no options to lock them to a specific language there.